# how to make multiuser?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

firstly I get this coding from http://www.webestools.com/scripts_tutorials-code-source-15-personal-message-system-in-php-mysql-pm-system-private-message-discussion.html

before this I  create user page and admin page using same coding. I edit same coding to see different user and admin page. I run at same browser at same time.. It run properly. But for this coding I make user and admin using same coding, same browser and run same time. I log in for admin first then log in for user. after I log in for user, I refresh admin page. session that I use in admin change to become like user page.

connexion.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');
?>
   <div class="header">
<a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $design; ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Members   Area" /></a>
</div>
<?php
//If the user is logged, we log him out
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
//We log him out by deleting the username and userid sessions
unset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['userid']);
?>
<div class="message">You have successfuly been loged out.<br />
<a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>">Home</a></div>
<?php
}
else
{
$ousername = '';
//We check if the form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
{
//We remove slashes depending on the configuration
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$ousername = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username']));
$password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
}
else
{
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = $_POST['password'];
}
//We get the password of the user
$req = mysql_query('select password,id from users where username="'.$username.'"');
$dn = mysql_fetch_array($req);
//We compare the submited password and the real one, and we check if the user exists
if($dn['password']==$password and mysql_num_rows($req)>0)
{
//If the password is good, we dont show the form
$form = false;
//We save the user name in the session username and the user Id in the session userid
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];
?>
<div class="message">You have successfuly been logged. You can access to your member area.<br />
<a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>">Home</a></div>
<?php
}
else
{
//Otherwise, we say the password is incorrect.
$form = true;
$message = 'The username or password is incorrect.';
}
}
else
{ 
$form = true;
}
if($form)
{
//We display a message if necessary
if(isset($message))
{
echo '<div class="message">'.$message.'</div>';
}
//We display the form
?>
<div class="content">
<form action="connexion.php" method="post"> Please type your IDs to log in:<br />
<div class="center">
<label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username"value="<?  
php echo htmlentities($ousername, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" /><br />
<label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password"   id="password" />br />
<input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</div> 
</form> 
</div>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include('config.php')
?>

<?php
//We display a welcome message, if the user is logged, we display it username
?>
Hello<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo ' '.htmlentities($_SESSION['username'],ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?>,<br />
Welcome on our website.<br />
You can <a href="users.php">see the list of users</a>.<br /><br />
 <?php
 //If the user is logged, we display links to edit his infos, to see his pms and to log out
 if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
 {
 //We count the number of new messages the user has
 $nb_new_pm = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(*) as nb_new_pm from pm where  ((user1="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user1read="no") or (user2="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user2read="no")) and id2="1"'));
//The number of new messages is in the variable $nb_new_pm
 $nb_new_pm = $nb_new_pm['nb_new_pm'];
//We display the links
?>
<a href="edit_infos.php">Edit my personnal informations</a><br />
<a href="list_pm.php">My personnal messages(<?php echo $nb_new_pm; ?> unread)</a><br />
<a href="connexion.php">Logout</a>
<?php
}
else
{
//Otherwise, we display a link to log in and to Sign up
?>
<a href="sign_up.php">Sign up</a><br />
<a href="connexion.php">Log in</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: The username is assigned to the session, so you can make it a multiuser setup by adding a new user/pass to your table. Saving your password in plain text is a bad idea. :-)

Comment: Using MySQL rather than MySQLi or PDO is also a bad idea

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very unspecific and you post way too much code, pls read the FAQ on how to ask in SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Add to your session some new indexes for admin, it will be like the following 
 if a normal user logs in after checking if he's admin or not you store the normal user session indexes like these that you're using..
`$_SESSION['username']` etc.. 
and if it's an admin logging in you store something like for example

```
$_SESSION['isAdmin'];
$_SESSION['adminName'];
```

etc..
and then you check for the Admin session in the admin panel..
and Then depending on the Session variables you decide what to show and what to not show, ask for login if there's no 'isAdmin' set..